# Items after appendix in the bookmarks

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, bookmarks

I have a problem in the bookmarks of my dissertation. The order in which the elements must appear are:

> Introduction
>
> chapters
>
> Appendices
>
> Bibliography
>
> Index.

However, in the bookmarks, the appendices, bibliography and index are as if they were appendices too. Can anyone help me?

Here are the commands I used and it generated.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introdução}

\chapter{1}
\chapter{2}
\chapter{3}

\cleardoublepage
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Apêndices}

\chapter{appendix 1}
\chapter{appendix 2}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Referências Bibliográficas}
\bibliography{References}
\bibliographystyle{acm}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\thispagestyle{empty}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\'{I}ndice Remissivo}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

More explicitly, here is a comparison of what I have and what I want:

[image]

Also notice the menu next. How do I separate them?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your document does not compile due to missing packages.

Comment: Your edits are contracting your question. You said that you don't want to have the bibliography and index being treated as appendix chapters, but they should be indented in the bookmarks?

Comment: Oi Christian, tentei explicar melhor em outro post que eu realmente quero. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315775/problems-with-pdf-summary-latex-toc

Comment: Your code doesn't load `hyperref` that's necessary for getting the bookmarks.

Comment: @LuisFernandoG.Bottaro: You changed the question and as such my former answer is useless :-(

Comment: Hi Christian, I'm sorry. I may have expressed myself wrong at first, but the question is the same. As I saw that the suggestions of the staff were not working, I tried to re-explain. Yet I too thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the `bookmarks` package. Here's a complete example; I also loaded `tocbibind` to avoid most of the `\addcontentsline` instructions.

The key is `\bookmarksetup{startatroot}` in the appropriate place.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introdução}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introdução}

\chapter{1}

Text\index{text}

\chapter{2}
\chapter{3}

\cleardoublepage
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Apêndices}

\chapter{appendix 1}
\chapter{appendix 2}

\bookmarksetup{startatroot}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Referências Bibliográficas}
\bibliography{References}
\bibliographystyle{acm}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Egreg, thank you very much!!! Your sugestion worked perfectly!